# Need to Avoid delays for 5k records in data table while updating excel sheet column from data table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq

//Need to update Excel sheet columns while retrieving data from data table     enter code here

```
     foreach (DataRow datarow in dt.Rows)
        {
            int[] colNumber = new int[] { 9,5,13,24,111,17,76,34,38 }; 
            rowcount += 1;
           for (int i = 0; i < colNumber.Length; i++)
            { string value = datarow[i].ToString();
           ws.Cells[rowcount, colNumber[i]] = value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: LINQ does not necessarily save time.

Comment: I'd rather output `Console.WriteLine(rowcount);` not *that frequent*, e.g. let's report about every `100th` record: `if (rowcount % 100 == 0) Console.WriteLine(rowcount);`

Comment: Actualy its updating 1 lakh records and its taking 4 hours for me to update. Linq can save time

Comment: @Sweeper- in such case actually it will help me to update excel sheet data  if i use linq

Answer (score 0):

The problem will not be solved by using EntityFramework as I'm afraid you are focusing on the wrong area. The main reason for this delay is that you are trying to access the worksheet object for each record in `dt.Rows`.

I recommend using GemBox.Spreadsheet for this purpose. You can directly attach the datatable to the worksheet. Also, you don't need to explicitly convert values to string.

```
----------
// Code sample.
private void Download()
{
    DataTable datatable=yourDatatable;// callStore Procedure to fetch  DataTable
    ExcelFile csvFile = new ExcelFile();//GemBox.Spreadsheet ExcelFile  
    ExcelWorksheet ws = csvFile.Worksheets.Add("YourWorkSheetName");

    if (ws != null)
    {
        ws.InsertDataTable(datatable, 0, 0, true);
        // Use MemoryStream to save or to send it to client as response.
    }
}

----------
```